# Ionic - block vertical scroll when don't need

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an app in ionic and in pages when I don't have scroll the page allows me like scroll anything... Don't show scroll, is like pull to refresh. I don't know how to explain that. Page is like elastic...
And I don't use pull to refresh, I check if I have any margin or padding but not. Maybe it's just a property...

For example in iphone messages app if we scroll top to bottom we see some margin in top like if the page were elastic..
Thank you

Comment: An image of the issue would help much

Comment: Are you trying to disable bounce effect? If yes you can try providing no-bounce tag for ion-content of the page